# Unlimited value for a select in form Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I want a select in my form, but the value of the select are dynamic (with ajax)

My entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true )
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $city;
```

My form:

```
$builder->add('city', 'choice',array('empty_value' => 'choice city', 'choices' => array() ));
```

But, I have:

> This value is not valid..

Because the city are not in the empty array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other solution with extend form theme:

In my form:

```
$builder->add('city', 'text',array('data' => 'choice city'));
```

And in my twig template

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block _template_defaultbundle_membertype_city_widget %} 
   <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }} ><option>{{ value }}</option></select> 
{% endblock %}
```

with "template_defaultbundle_membertype_city" is the id of the input

Answer (score 1):

Since the city field is a simple string and is not related to a table, simply:

1. Render the field as a simple input text;
2. Attach to the input field the Javascript for city-autocompletion through Ajax to fill the input
3. Then you are ready to submit

or:

1. Render the field as text.
2. Hide it in the template
3. Attach a select through javascript in place of the text-input
4. Use that select to render the list of cities
5. On submit get the value from the select and put it as value of the input field.

This approach can be used also to set value for visual widgets, like a *star rating*.

Comment: Ok! Now I understood your problem!

Comment: I handled something like that in the past! Avoid using choices! The choice is built by the autocompletion (see jQuery for instance). So simply attach the library to a simple input field!

Comment: NO! You render a simple input field. Then you attach the JS library to that input field. See [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example with jQuery (look at Remote JSONP datasource case that really fits your needs)

Comment: I really **need a select**, so in my case i have to transform input to select with js.. there is no alternative to do it?

Comment: How can you render it as a select if you have to load the list of choices with AJAX by following the user input? This is the workflow: 1) the user write cityname in an input field; 2) the ajax receive the input and make a call to get the list of city that maches the input; 3) the js render that list as a dropdown select that is shown just below the input field; 4) the user make a choice; 5) the choice is shown in the text field!

Comment: `$.get('page?zipcode='+ $('#zipcode').val(), function(data) {
$('#idselect').html( data );
});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22838/discussion-between-roldifion-and-jeanvaljean)